# how to update existing job data map in quartz

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I have configured a quartz scheduler with simple trigger and a job with job data map in Spring.

I want to later change the job data map and want the scheduler to pick up the latest job data map.

Is there a way to configure it in spring context xml file or tell spring to update the trigger with the new job data map?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7190882).  Basically, use @PersistJobDataAfterExecution on the job class. (It usually goes with @DisallowConcurrentExecution.)